# Call a python script multiple times form another python script and pass a dataframe as an input

Tags: python, pandas

I have two python files generator.py and createexcell.py.
generator.py creates a python dataframe "df1" that I need to pass to createexcell.py
Is there any way so that I could **store "df1" from generator.py to a variable "df2" in createexcell.py** ?

Comment: you could invoke the code that creates `df1` in your target script

Comment: Just to add to the suggestion made by Umar.H: You would need to import the function, which generates `df1` in generator.py, in createexcell.py to be able to invoke it there.

Comment: df1 is a huge data frame I want it to be created only once. After the creation of df1 I want to run createexcell.py multiple times with df1 and another variable as input.
createexcell.py has multiple functions and I want to run this entire program and not just one of its functions.
Thanks in advance.